# Show each person data on a separate page using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a sql query which provides me information with each person's information, emergency medical information, etc.
Looking to create a report which provides me this data for each of the records on a separate page.
So for the example below, personid 100 data would show in one page, personid 101 data on another page and so on.
I've used installed Visual Studio Reporting Services, but not sure where to start 
in order to create a report like this. I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Shell 2010.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. As always, thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: You will probably need to start with a simple table control on your report design tab, and after binding to your dataset add a grouping region grouped by personid. When you create a group on the control you can edit the group properties to add page breaks for each new group (personid) that appears in the results.

Comment: Can I make the page look like a form instead of a typical row report? For example, can I have the first name/last name field be at the top of the report, then have the medications in the middle of the page, electronic signature at the bottom etc? So more like a form where these question/answers are populating?